# Is the limit function $f$ in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of $L^1([-M,M], \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu_X)$ functions with $f_n:[-M,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that it converges uniformly to some $f$. We need to show that $f$ is also in $L^1([-M,M], \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu_X)$. How can you use uniform convergence to show that $\int|f|d\mu_X<\infty$?
I got the feeling there is an easy answer why but I don't see it.

Comment: Is the measure finite?

Comment: @copper.hat yes

Comment: How could you bound $\int |f(x)-f_n(x)| d \mu_{X}(x)$ if $f_n \to f$ uniformly?

Comment: by $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$?

Comment: Well, its a start, but that is not an upper bound in the integral unless it is a probability measure.

Comment: I was thinking $2M\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ but that's only true if $\mu_X$ is the Lebesgue measure right?

Comment: If the measure is finite then $\mu_X ([-M,M])$ is a finite number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105318/discussion-between-keep-on-cruising-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|f-f_n\|_1 = \int_{[-M,M]} |f(x) -f_n(x)| d \mu_X(x) \le \sup_{x \in [-M,M]} |f(x) -f_n(x)| \int_{[-M,M]}  d \mu_X(x) = \sup_{x \in [-M,M]} |f(x) -f_n(x)| \mu_X([-M,M])$.

Note that $\|f\|_1 \le \|f-f_n\|_1 + \|f_n \|_1$, hence $f$ is integrable.

Comment: one question, we have now shown that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$ sense, but does this also imply that $f$ in $L^1$ (maybe a very stupid question).

Comment: I added a note.

Answer (score 1):

How about:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int |f| d\mu_X &= \int |f_n + f - f_n| d \mu_X \leq \int |f_n| d \mu_X + \int|f-f_n| d \mu_X \\
&\leq \int |f_n| d \mu_X + \epsilon \mu_X([-M,M]) < \infty \\
\end{aligned}$$
(by choosing $n$ large enough so that $|f-f_n|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in [-M,M]$)